# Use order with MEDOO

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

I'm trying to use order by, I want to use this select:

```
Select * from tarea where cod_tarea = $row order by estado;

$tarea_data = $database->select("tarea","*",['cod_tarea' => $row], ["ORDER" => "estado"]);
$tarea_data = $database->select("tarea","*",['cod_tarea' => $row, "ORDER" => "estado"]);
```

But doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

According to an example in [the docs](https://medoo.in/api/select), you can do it like this:

```php
$tarea_data = $database->select(
    "tarea",
    "*",
    [
        'cod_tarea' => $row, 
        "ORDER" => [
            "estado" => "ASC",
        ]        
    ]
);
```

Note that you should use `DESC` for descending in case you want a descending order of items. I am assuming you meant ascending here.

Comment: Not working :/ the estado is a ENUM... maybe thats why?

Comment: Should still be working. Can you please explain in more detail in your question what you are expecting and what is happening instead?